# undefined method `remember' for #<ApplicationHelperTest:0x000000075bf4d0>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am following tutorials mentioned https://www.railstutorial.org/book/log_in_log_out.

While I am executing a test with given command :
bundle exec rake test TEST=test/helpers/sessions_helper_test.rb

I am encountering Errors given below :

1) Error:
ApplicationHelperTest#test_current_user_returns_nil_when_remember_digest_is_wrong:
NoMethodError: undefined method `remember' for #<ApplicationHelperTest:0x000000075bf4d0>
    test/helpers/sessions_helper_test.rb:7:in`setup'

2) Error:
ApplicationHelperTest#test_Current_user_returns_right_user_with_session_is_nill:
NoMethodError: undefined method `remember' for #<ApplicationHelperTest:0x00000007702400>
    test/helpers/sessions_helper_test.rb:7:in`setup'

---

I have a helper class methods defined in /apps/helpers/session_helper.rd.
--remember method is part of this class .. still the /test/helpers/sessions_helper_test is unable to find that method.

Code for     /test/helpers/sessions_helper_test.rb file is

```
require 'test_helper'

class ApplicationHelperTest < ActionView::TestCase


  def setup
    @user = users(:michael)
    remember(@user)
  end

  test "Current_user returns right user with session is nill" do
    assert_equal @user, current_user
    assert is_logged_in?
  end

  test "current_user returns nil when remember digest is wrong" do
    @user.update_attribute(:remember_digest, User.digest(User.new_token))
    assert_nil current_user
  end

end
```

This is a code for module SessionsHelper

```
    module SessionsHelper

  # Logs in the given user.
  def log_in(user)
    session[:user_id] = user.id
  end

  # Remembers a user in a persistent session.
  def remember(user)
    user.remember
    cookies.permanent.signed[:user_id] = user.id
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
  end

  # Returns the current logged-in user (if any).
  def current_user
    if (user_id = session[:user_id])
      @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: user_id)
    elsif (user_id = cookies.signed[:user_id])
      user = User.find_by(id: user_id)
      if user && user.authenticated?(cookies[:remember_token]) #here is an Evaluation Magic for a given Method
        log_in user
        @current_user = user
      end
    end
  end
  # Returns true if the user is logged in, false otherwise.
  def logged_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end

  # Logs out the current user. # Actions (Set digest to Nill) (Delete the Cookie) (Delete the Session) (Set current_user variable to nill)
  def log_out
    forget(current_user)
    session.delete(:user_id)
    @current_user = nil
  end


  def forget(user)
    user.forget # is to forget the user .. means set th remember_digest to nill -- Go to User Model
    cookies.delete(:user_id)
    cookies.delete(:remember_token)
  end

end
```

Users.yml file is :

```
# Read about fixtures at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FixtureSet.html

michael:
  name: Michael Example
  email: michael@example.com
  password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %>

archer:
  name: Sterling Archer
  email: duchess@example.gov
  password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %>
```

-----------------Got the Solution -------------------

you need to include HelperModule to test Module .. 
after fix code for test/helpers/sessions_helper_test.rb will look like

```
require 'test_helper'

class ApplicationHelperTest < ActionView::TestCase
  include SessionsHelper # This line is added to  code.



  def setup
    @user = users(:michael)
    remember(@user)
  end

  test "Current_user returns right user with session is nill" do
    assert_equal @user, current_user
    assert is_logged_in?
  end

  test "current_user returns nil when remember digest is wrong" do
    @user.update_attribute(:remember_digest, User.digest(User.new_token))
    assert_nil current_user
  end

end
```

Comment: paste the remember method. Doesn't seem to be existing.

Comment: can you post the content of sessions_helper?

Comment: THanks astreal and  Jorge de los Santos .. I found the solution .. the moment I include SessionsHelper module to my class ApplicationHeperTest .. this thigs works ..  :   Could you please help me with reason why I need to include these files specifically .. : Is ruby test are not allowed to access methods from their respective helper classes ?

Comment: @One including the module in the `ApplicationHelperTest` brings it into scope. Modules can be a strange beast for example you could have done `module SessionsHelper; extend self; YOUR_METHODS; end;` then called it with `SessionsHelper.remember(@user)` but using inclusion alows you to call the method directly as if you had typed it into `ApplicationHelperTest` itself.

Answer (score 4):

Following the tutorial as well and had a similar issue. You can avoid using include by updating your class from:

```
class ApplicationHelperTest < ActionView::TestCase
```

to:

```
class SessionsHelperTest < ActionView::TestCase
```